# How do I create an HD wallet and child wallets in Solana?

Tags: solana, pki, key-pair

I know how to [make a wallet in Solana](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html):

```js
const keypair = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSeed(seed);
```

Similar to '[what is a HD wallet for Ether and how to create one using nodejs?'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/what-is-a-hd-wallet-for-ether-and-how-to-create-one-using-nodejs#33440)
 I'd like to create an HD wallet using Solana.

Specifically, I have created a keypair and would like to create a child keypair. I can't find any references to creating HD wallets in the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html).

But how do I make child wallets? Here's what I'd do in Ethereum:

```js
var mnemonic = "seed sock milk ...";
var path = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0";

var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(path).getWallet();
```

**How do I create an HD wallet and child wallets in Solana?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BIP-44 `derivePath` helper for this purpose. From the [Solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/keypairs-and-wallets.html#how-to-restore-a-keypair-from-a-mnemonic-phrase):

```js
import { derivePath } from 'ed25519-hd-key';

const mnemonic =
  "neither lonely flavor argue grass remind eye tag avocado spot unusual intact";
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic, ""); // (mnemonic, password)
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const path = `m/44'/501'/${i}'/0'`;
  const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(derivePath(path, seed.toString("hex")).key);
  console.log(`${path} => ${keypair.publicKey.toBase58()}`);
}
```

Comment: I've sent Solana a PR to make the docs more apparent! https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-cookbook/pull/391#pullrequestreview-1032964999